# Oracle DB query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need an Oracle DB query where I can get the Primary keys, Data type and the length of an Attribute in BYTES.

Currently I am doing:

```
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P' 
  AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
  AND cons.owner like 'DBP%';
```

where I am getting the table name, column name which is a primary key. Now I need the data type and the length of the column in BYTES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with `all_tab_columns` to get the data type and (maximum) length in bytes.

```
select
    cols.table_name,
    cols.column_name,
    tab_cols.data_type,
    tab_cols.data_length
from all_constraints cons
join all_cons_columns cols
    on cons.owner = cols.owner
    and cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
join all_tab_columns tab_cols
    on cols.owner = tab_cols.owner
    and cols.table_name = tab_cols.table_name
    and cols.column_name = tab_cols.column_name
where cons.constraint_type = 'P'
    and cons.owner like 'DBP%';
```

You didn't specify but I assume you want the maximum length.  If you want the actual used size for the column you could use `AVG_COL_LENGTH` and multiply it by `NUM_ROWS` in `ALL_TABLES`.